# Define a value in an if else statement and reuse it later (newbie to php)

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I don't know much about php or coding, I'm just trying. I have tried to find a solution online, but I don't even know what to look for...

I want to make a site where you can create (and get an id to share) or join (with that id). I have three php files: create, join and result. In create and join are the input forms. result.php looks like this

```
if(isset($_POST['create'])){
    $ins = mysql_query("INSERT ...");
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
}elseif(isset($_POST['join'])){
    $id = $_POST ['id'];
}
```

That works just fine. But I want to use the id later and it is only set on create or join. And I want to use the id on the same site to show result.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use sessions to store such information.

For example after the if else statement you can do this

`$_SESSION['id'] = $id;`

Now your id is stored in the session and you can reuse it in your other php files by getting it from there:

`$id = $_SESSION['id'];`

I hope this helps you.